# A question about the polar equation $r=ln(\theta)$

Tags: logarithms, area, polar-coordinates

Take the polar equation r=ln(theta) for theta between $0$ and $2\pi$.
[image: Equation of r=ln(theta) between 0 and 2pi][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA140.png)
In this, we have a loop that connects at a point $(x,y)$ for $2$ unique points $(r_1,\theta_1)$ and ($r_2,\theta_2)$. There are $2$ questions about this I would like to know the answer to and how you would find it.

1. At what point $(x,y)$ does this loop have the intersection shown in the image, and
2. What is the area of the loop within this equation? I understand the equation is $1/2$ of the integral of $r^2 d\theta$ from $\theta_1$ to $\theta_2$, I just don't know how the get the $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ for this equation.

Comment: "the connection"??  What connection?  Oh... you mean *INTERSECTS* or *INTERSECTION*?

Comment: you know, the points (r1,theta1) and (r2,theta2) where they share the same (x,y) coordinate.

Comment: Called an "intersection."  Got it.

Comment: To ask a question on this forum, you need to do more.  You need to show your own efforts.  For that intersection point, one set of coordinates has negative $r$ and one has positive $r$.  What next?  You will need to solve part 1 before you can start with part 2.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

The point of intersection represents two points with the same absolute value of $r$, but with different values of $\theta$ seperated by an integer multiple of $\pi$. Since we are restricted to $[0,2\pi]$, this would be $\pi$

$$r_1 = \ln\theta_1$$

$$r_2 = \ln\theta_2 = \ln(\theta_1 + \pi)$$

Since log is an increasing function, we have $r_2 = -r_1, r_1 < 0$

$$\ln(\theta_1) + \ln(\theta_1 + \pi) = 0$$

$$\implies \ln(\theta_1(\theta_1 + \pi)) = 0$$

$$\implies \theta_1 = \frac{1}{\theta_1 + \pi}$$

Comment: Or possibly an integer multiple of $\pi$...

Comment: Not really, since it has to coincide - odd multiples of $\pi$ would shift it by half a rotation in the polar space

Comment: An issue I see with this hint is that I had stated that theta is restricted between 0 and 2pi. And since the intersection can't happen at theta=0, then the difference between theta1 and theta2 can't be an integer multiple of 2pi, thus no intersection at all? I did check using a calculator to see if it was just weirdness with Desmos, but it shows the same pattern so I'm just left sorta confused on how to properly solve it.

Comment: @DhanviSreenivasan: note that since $r$ transitions from negative to positive, an odd multiple of $\pi$ matches this...

Comment: Made the edits, now it should be fine